# eBay API GetOrders How to get the shipping cost that the seller paid

Tags: python, ebay-api, ebay-sdk

So every time I make this call to the API, every order has a `ShippingServiceSelected.ShippingServiceCost.value` Is always 0 for every order. I am guaranteed that every order had shipping bought through eBay because they are the items I sold. I am on Python and doing this through the eBaySDK module that can be found here: https://github.com/timotheus/ebaysdk-python

The call I am making to the API uses the arguments: `CreatedTimeFrom`, `CreatedTimeTo`, `IncludeFinalValueFee: True`, and `Pagination.EntriesPerPage: 100`

Thank you in advance for helping.

Comment: It is not possible. You should get shipping cost in ShippingServiceSelected.ShippingServiceCost. Please check your orders.

Answer (score 0):

Set the value of element  in the XML as RETURNALL, This would return all the data in a  particular order and also the shipping details.

Sample Xml will be --

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetOrdersRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
 <RequesterCredentials>
   <eBayAuthToken>ABC...123</eBayAuthToken>
 </RequesterCredentials>
<DetailLevel>ReturnAll</DetailLevel>
 <CreateTimeFrom>2015-12-01T20:34:44.000Z</CreateTimeFrom>
 <CreateTimeTo>2015-12-10T20:34:44.000Z</CreateTimeTo>
 <OrderRole>Seller</OrderRole>
 <OrderStatus>Active</OrderStatus>
</GetOrdersRequest>
```